# How to enable the second serial port on old vm AT&T SVR4?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, serial-port, svr4

Usually one serial port is sufficient to control via minicom the old SVR4 on Qemu (I know is a very old system, is unsafe, etc..).
I have set those two ports on configuration of vm

```
<serial type="pty">
  <source path="/dev/pts/1"/>
  <target type="isa-serial" port="0">
    <model name="isa-serial"/>
  </target>
  <alias name="serial0"/>
</serial>

serial type="pty">
  <source path="/dev/pts/2"/>
  <target type="isa-serial" port="1">
    <model name="isa-serial"/>
  </target>
  <alias name="serial1"/>
</serial>
```

But on start, only one port is enabled

```
find /dev/ -name *tty* -print
/dev/systty
/dev/tty00
/dev/tty
/dev/tty00s
/dev/tty00h
```

So I try to rebuild the kernel. On SVR4 to rebuild the kernel first I make the changes in
the file /etc/conf/sdevice.d/asy

```
asy     Y       1       7       1       4       3f8     3ff     0       0
asy     Y       1       7       1       3       2f8     2ff     0       0
```

the syntax is simple: asy is the driver Y enable it, 1 7 1 I don't know, 3 is the interrupt (on all my system irq 3 is used by the second serial port, 4 by the first). 3f8-3ff and 2f8-2ff are the port interval, 0 0 I don't know

Then I rebuild the kernel with idbuild.
After reboot, same situation.
If I edit the file

/etc/conf/node.d/asy

```
asy     tty00   c       0
asy     term/00 c       0
asy     tty00s  c       0
asy     tty00h  c       128
asy     term/00s        c       0
asy     term/00h        c       128

asy     tty01   c       1
asy     term/01 c       1
asy     tty01s  c       1
asy     tty01h  c       128
asy     term/01s        c       1
asy     term/01h        c       128
```

and recreate the nodes

```
idmknod -s
```

I have this strange situation

ls -ld /dev/tty*

```
crw-rw-rw-   1 bin      bin       16,  0 Dec 25 19:31 /dev/tty
crw--w----   1 myuser   tty        3,  0 Mar 27 05:20 /dev/tty00
crw-rw-rw-   1 root     root       3,128 Mar 27 04:26 /dev/tty00h
crw-rw-rw-   1 root     root       3,  0 Mar 27 04:26 /dev/tty00s
crw--w----   1 root     root       3,  0 Mar 27 05:20 /dev/tty01
crw-rw-rw-   1 root     root       3,128 Mar 27 04:26 /dev/tty01h
crw-rw-rw-   1 root     root       3,  0 Mar 27 04:26 /dev/tty01s
```

All files use the major number 3.
Why the 4 is complete ignored? What I miss? Probably a bug in the kernel or what else?
On all my system the two serials are recognized, modern (Linux) and old (Sco Unix).
I see with SVR4 that it cannot see any serial port (except the first)
on qemu but also on 86box and bochs.